# Check values of a mapping using Foundry

Tags: solidity, foundry

For testing, I deployed my contract locally on anvil and am trying to interact with it using cast.
To verify the correct working of my contract, I would like to check the values in a mapping after updating them. I think I should be using [`cast index`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-index?highlight=cast%20index#cast-index). My current approach:

- Start anvil by running `anvil`. Copy the address and private key of the first wallet into `export WALLET_1=0x...` & `export PRIVATE_KEY_1=0x...`
- Deploy: `forge script script/Contract.s.sol:ContractScript --fork-url http://localhost:8545 --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY_1 --broadcast`. The resulting contract address goes into `export CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x...`
- Publish a message: `cast send $CONTRACT_ADDRESS "addKVpair(bytes32, uint)" 0x1 10 --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY_1 --from $WALLET_1`
- Read mapping at key: `cast index bytes32 0x1 0`. I assumed that the slot number should be `0` because it's the first declared variable.
- Result: `0x14184318b4299964f96ff8dfa1db97fc8a28d66e8c4434c0773f43adc6062152` which is not 10.
- If I try to read the value of a non-exiting key, I get a similar, non-zero, value.

What is going wrong? What would be the best approach?

For reference, my contract is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract Contract {
    mapping (bytes32 => uint) public mapTest;

    function addKVpair(bytes32 key, uint value) public {
        mapTest[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The storage location of mappings and dynamic arrays in a contract can be calculated by
`cast index [key-type] [key-value] [slot]`.

If you want to know what is going on this particular slot, use
`cast storage [contract address] [mapping key]`.

[Here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) are details on how the slot is calculated.

In this case, do

```bash
>> cast index bytes32 0x1 0
0xabc..
>> cast storage $CONTRACT_ADDRESS 0xabc..
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
```

which is 10.